# How to assert multiple attribute element in Zend_Test?

Tags: zend-test

For example:

How can I assert this input?

$this->assertQuery( "input[name="user_name][type='hidden']") can not find any content.

Of couse $this->assertQuery( "input[name='user_name']) will work well, but I need to use type and name attributes together.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `assertQuery` can, use `assertXPath`:

`$this->assertXPath("//input[@name='user_name'][@type='hidden']);`